# time slot not working properly

Tags: ios, swift

I am making one ios App where showing time slot my time slot is like current time will be first time and after that it will start with 30 30 min difference.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    lazy var timeArray = [Any]()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timeSlots(startTime: "11:44 AM", endTime: "6:00 PM", leadTime: 60, timeInterval: 30)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func timeSlots(startTime:String , endTime:String , leadTime:Int, timeInterval:Int){
        formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"

        var startingTime = formatter.date(from: startTime)
        let endingTime = formatter.date(from: endTime)

        var firstTimeSlot = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute , value: leadTime, to: startingTime!)
        timeArray.append(formatter.string(from: firstTimeSlot!).localizedUppercase)


        formatter.dateFormat = "mm"
        let newMin = formatter.string(from: firstTimeSlot!)

        print(formatter.string(from: firstTimeSlot!))

        formatter.dateFormat = "hh"
        let newHour = formatter.string(from: firstTimeSlot!)

        print(formatter.string(from: firstTimeSlot!))


        var i = 0


        if Int(newMin)! < 30 {

            let myNewHour:Int =  Int(newHour)!
            let newTimeIS = "30" + String(myNewHour)
            firstTimeSlot = formatter.date(from: newTimeIS)
        }
        else {

            let myNewHour:Int =  Int(newHour)!
            let newTimeIS = "00" + String(myNewHour)
            firstTimeSlot = formatter.date(from: newTimeIS)

        }

        formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
        print(formatter.string(from: firstTimeSlot!))

        while startingTime! <= endingTime! {

            guard let firstTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute , value: i*timeInterval, to: firstTimeSlot!)  else {return}

            print(formatter.string(from: firstTimeSlot!))
            print(formatter.string(from: firstTime))
            print(formatter.string(from: startingTime!))


            startingTime = firstTime
            timeArray.append(formatter.string(from: firstTime).localizedUppercase)
            i += 1

            if firstTime == endingTime! {
                break
            }
        }
        print(timeArray)
    }
}
```

if m setting first time 11:44 or 11 AM next should be 12PM but its taking 12AM 1AM ike this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this answer solves your problem!
Kindly vote up if it does :)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timeArray = [Any]()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        timeSlots(startTime: "11:44 AM", endTime: "6:00 PM", timeInterval: 30)
    }

    func timeSlots(startTime:String , endTime:String , timeInterval:Int){
        formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"

        let startingTime = formatter.date(from: startTime)
        var endingTime = formatter.date(from: endTime)

        if endingTime! <= startingTime! {
            return
        }

        formatter.dateFormat = "mm"
        var min = formatter.string(from: startingTime!)
        formatter.dateFormat = "hh"
        var hour = formatter.string(from: startingTime!)

        if Int(min)! <= 30  {
            min = "30"
        } else {
            min = "00"
            hour = String(Int(hour)! + 1)
        }

        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        var tempStartTime = formatter.date(from: "\(hour):\(min)")
        let endTimeString = formatter.string(from: endingTime!)
        endingTime = formatter.date(from: endTimeString)

        formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"

        timeArray.append(formatter.string(from: tempStartTime!).localizedUppercase)

        while tempStartTime! < endingTime! {
            guard let timeSlot = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute , value: timeInterval, to: tempStartTime!)  else {return}

            //print("timeSlot: \(formatter.string(from: timeSlot))")

            tempStartTime = timeSlot
            timeArray.append(formatter.string(from: timeSlot).localizedUppercase)
        }

        print(timeArray)
    }
```

Comment: @Trung Anh Pham.   Thank you for Indentation editing suggestion. Looks neat now